# Extract emails from a data dump using Python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a data dump from which I am trying to extract all emails.

This is the code I have written using BeautifulSoup

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = urllib2.urlopen("file:///users/home/Desktop/emails.html").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
email = raw_input(soup)
match = re.findall(r'&lt;(.*?)&gt;', email)
if match:
    print match
```

Sample data dump

```html
<tr><td><a href="http://abc.gov.com/comments/24-April/file.html">for educational purposes only</a></td>
<td>7418681641 &lt;sampleemail@gmail.com&gt;</td>
<td>advqos@abc.gov.com</td>
<td nowrap="">24-04-2015 10.31</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://abc.gov.com/comments/24-April/test.html">no_subject</a></td>
<td>John &lt;someemail@gmail.com&gt;</td>
<td>advqos@abc.gov.com</td>
<td nowrap="">24-04-2015 11.28</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://abc.gov.com/comments/24-April/test.html">something</a></td>
<td>Mark &lt;123random@gmail.com&gt;</td>
<td>test@abc.gov.com</td>
<td nowrap="">24-04-2015 11.28</td>
<td align="center">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="http://abc.gov.com/comments/24-April/abc.html">some data</a></td>
```

I can clearly see that emails are listed between a `&lt;` and a `&gt;` tag. I am trying to use a regex to identify all emails and print them. However, on execution, instead of only extracting emails (one email per line), the whole file is getting printed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't understand your code at all. Why are you using `urllib2` to open a local file? Just use `with open("/path/to/file.html") as f: soup = BeautifulSoup(f)`. Next, what do you expect `raw_input(soup)` to do? Finally, why are you doing a regex search of the text when you just started using an HTML parser?

Comment: @MattDMo: Ahh yes you are correct sir. Could have simply opened it.Didn't know that raw_input takes an input from user. I was under the assumption that it will parse the soup variable into a string. Without raw_input line, I am getting an error saying that re.findall function was expecting a string as the 2nd parameter in the string

Answer (score 1):

Your example actually works

```
re.findall(r'\&lt;(.*?)\&gt;',your_data_bump)=
['sampleemail@gmail.com', 'someemail@gmail.com', '123random@gmail.com']
```

Comment: Thanks this actually worked. I simply changed this line to match = re.findall(r'&lt;(.*?)&gt;', str(email)) and then printed the values.

Answer (score 0):

## Assuming your data dump is in a text file called text.txt:

```
import re
# Make sure the text file is in the same folder as the python file.
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    matches = re.findall(r'&lt;(.+?)&gt;',f.read())
print('\n'.join(matches))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can parse to the tag you are looking for using `find_all` method of `BeautifulSoup`. Here is the code. (I have stored the sample file as `a.html`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = open("a.html",'r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
rows = soup.find_all('tr') # find all rows using tag 'tr'
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')  # find all columns using 'td' tag
    if len(cols)>1:
        email_id_string = cols[1].text # get the text of second element of list (contains email id element)
        email_id = email_id_string[ email_id_string.find("<")+1 : email_id_string.find(">") ] (get only the email id between < and > )
        print email_id
```

Comment: This won't work, because there are many `<td>` elements that don't contain email addresses.

Comment: If email ID is present , its present as second column, hence i have checked that using `if condition`

Comment: No you haven't. You've simply checked if there are more than one `<td>` elements per `<tr>`, and if so you take the second td and assume it contains an email, which for arbitrary HTML is not a valid assumption. The OP posted a very simple example, while I imagine the actual data is not as well-structured as this. Your solution needs to be *much* more robust than it currently is.

Comment: Yes , you are right. This solution is entirely based on what OP has posted. I have referred this solution using given sample HTML file. However, OP can still find a way from this how to proceed further using simple iterations of BeautifulSoup without getting into more complexity